# Destroy action in controller doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, crud, destroy

I can't manage to get my destroy action in my controller to work. I've read that you have to include default javascript libraries to delete, but I've done that (at least I think I have), and it still doesn't work. Background on my app: articles are "recipes", so my controller is called recipes_controller. Here's the code from my recipes_controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /recipes
  # GET /recipes.json
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  # GET /recipes/1
  # GET /recipes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # DELETE /recipes/1
  # DELETE /recipes/1.json
  def destroy
    @recipe.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to recipes_url, notice: 'Recipe was  
      successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_recipe
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :body, :published_at, :category_ids => [])
  end
end
```

Then, here's the code for my application.html.erb file, where I thought i had included the default javascript libraries:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>inherentlydope</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>d
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>

<%= content_tag :p, notice, :class => 'notice' if notice.present? %>
<%= content_tag :p, alert, :class => 'alert' if alert.present? %>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Then, here's my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: "recipes#index"
  #resources :comments
  resources :recipes do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :users
  resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy] #always deal with session, not sessionS
  get '/login' => "sessions#new",as: "login"
  get '/logout' => "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
end
```

Comment: Can you post your model too?

Comment: Actually the view with which you are trying to destroy a record would be helpful. Make sure you are doing a delete request

Comment: 1) any javascript errors? (see browser console); 2) did a DELETE request sent from browser? (see browser network or rails log); 3) did rails handle the request as you expected? (see if the request actually sent to the destroy action)

Comment: in short could you check what exactly the error is / where it is instead of just "doesn't work"?

Comment: you should also make sure that `jquery_ujs` is included in the js manifest

Comment: What errors are you getting in the server console?

Comment: I fixed the issue - in my application.html.erb file, the :defaults option is no longer supported for the javascript_include_tag. It has to be :application